# How to prove a solution is indeed a constrained minimum?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm reading the following example on Heath's *Scientific Computing* (page 266, second edition if anyone has it).

"Minimize $f(x_1,x_2)=2\pi x_1(x_1+x_2)$ subject to $g(x_1,x_2)=\pi x^2_1x_2-V$" (minimize the surface area of a cylinder subject to a constant of its volume).

Using Lagrange Multipliers and assuming $V=1000cm^3$, the approximate solutions are $x_1=5.4$, $x_2=10.8$ and $\lambda = -0.37$.

Then $H_f(x)=2\pi \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$ and $H_g(x)=2\pi \begin{bmatrix} x_2 & x_1 \\ x_1 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$, so that 
$B(x^*, \lambda ^*)=2\pi \begin{bmatrix} 2 +x_2\lambda & 1+x_1\lambda \\ 1x_1\lambda  & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$.

Computing we get $B(x^*, \lambda ^*)=2\pi \begin{bmatrix} -12.6 & -6.3 \\ -6.3 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$.

Now here comes the part that I don't get

"The matrix is not positive definite, but that is to be expected. To consider the appropiate subspace we compute a null vector $z$ (i.e., a basis for the one dimensional null space) for $J_g(x^*)= \begin{bmatrix} 369 & 92.3 \end{bmatrix}$ and obtain $z=\begin{bmatrix} -0.243 & 0.970 \end{bmatrix}^T$, so that $z^TBz=2.23$, which is positive confirming that the point found is indeed a constrained minimum. The optimal value is $f(x^*)=554cm^2$ of surfaced area".

How can I compute $z$?. What is it?. Sadly, I think I haven't got that part of the theory of constrained optimization.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's just saying find $(x,y)$ such that $369 x + 92.3 y = 0$.

Comment: Ok, I see it. Could you elaborate on the theory behind this? The idea that a sufficient condition for a constrained minimum is that the matrix $B(x^*, \lambda)$ at the critical point be positive definite on the tangent space to the constraint surface, which is simply the null space of $J_g(x^*)$. Seems I haven't quite get this part of equality-constrained optimality.

Comment: Sure.  So, you're constrained to a constant value of $g$, so you're only interested in what happens to $f$ in directions that are tangent to the space $g$ equal to a constant.  This tangent space is the null space of $J_g$.  When you restrict $B$ to that subspace, it is positive definite, so the critical point is a minimum when subject to the constraint.  In other words, if we could move off of $g=constant$, we could get $f$ smaller, but restricted to $g=constant$ this is a minimum.